# Unable to deploy SAPUI5 application with 404 error

Tags: sapui5, project, sap-cloud-platform, sap-web-ide

I have created an app through the SAP Web IDE Full-Stack and attempted to deploy it to the SAP Cloud Platform. This appears to work fine, however, when I then go to use the deployed link it just displays "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found".

I tried looking for other solutions but had no luck. Here is my `neo-app.json` file:

[image: neo-app]

And this is my apps structure:

[image: app structure]

So it appears that it is pointing to the index correctly, the only thing I am noticing is that in the generated `dist` it does not contain an index file. I have tried manually adding it but it is being removed upon project rebuilt.

Could this be the problem? If so how can I fix this?

[image: dist file]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: any more descriptions on the error you are getting? Like associated text

Comment: Hi Nandan, the only error shown in the console when trying to load the app is 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()' . When deploying the app to the Cloud Platform I can see the message '2:40:36 PM (Application Index) URI block was not added to the manifest.json file: Request failed: error URI: /sap/flp/flpnwc/sap/bc/ui2/app_index?sap.app/id=Z_LE.Z_LE&fields=sap.app/id,html5AppName'. Though this doesn't stop the deployment, just seems like a warning so not sure if it is related or not

Answer (score 2):

The folder structure of your SAP UI5 app is very important during deployment. Ideally you should have your `webapp` folder and your `dist` folder as the only folders in the root directory of the app. (It's okay if you do not have a `dist` folder).

Your `neo-app.json` file should also have a line like `"welcomeFile":"webapp/index.html",` pointing to your `index.html` or the root file of your application.

This should mostly solve the **HTTP Status 404** issues.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to fix the issue, not entirely sure why, but upon removing the ExternalLib folder i can now successfully deploy and run the app on the SAP cloud platform